# Applying values to highest terminal segments in channel network using PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, dem, rivers, strahler

I extracted a channel network from a dem but due to some technical difficulties the layer had some discontinuities. So after filling them, i suddenly realised that the Strahler orders it gave me were wrong and i want to create a query on Postgresql that might work around the issue for me. What i am trying to do right now is simple, get the segments placed highest in altitude at the end of a series of channels in the shapefile i made beforehand and apply to them a value of 1 in a column i created. In short i want postgre to read my shapes and find the places where he can't find another shape placed higher and intersecting with him.

I loaded my dem raster in PostgreSQL, and already used a query to extract the mean altitudes for each segment of my vector layer